# Añadir varios valores a un diccionario en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

estoy intentando la creación de una clasificación de puntos por equipo. He supuesto que como cada equipo en sus puntuaciones tiene una leyenda que indica el significado de cada puntuación, se harían dos diccionarios, de la siguiente manera:

````
``` {equipo:{puntuaciones}} ```
````

Tras ello se pide que introduzca las puntuaciones en un input de la forma 
EQUIPO PUNTUACIÓN, pero no me deja realizarlo, ¿Alguna solocuión?

Comment: ¿Qué contendría "puntuaciones"? ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo real del diccionario con su diccionario interno? Por otro lado ¿por qué "no te deja"? ¿Aparece algún error? ¿Cuál? ¿Y cuál es el código que has escrito que te produce ese error?

Answer (score 0):

con un ejemplo como decía el compañero, mejor. Con lo que nos comentas, necesitas añadir otra clave (key) al, llamémoslo así, sub-diccionario, tipo:

```
{"equipo": "nombre",
 "puntuacion":
   {"puntuacion 1": XX,
    "puntuacion 2": XX,
    ...
    "puntuacion N": XX
   }
}
```

pero en este caso, lo más simple sería añadir una lista:

```
{"equipo 1": [XX, XX, XX, ..., XX],
 "equipo 2": [XX, XX, XX, ..., XX],
 ...
 "equipo N": [XX, XX, XX, ..., XX]
}
```

(al añadir más resultados, recuperas la lista y haces un `list.append()`)

o si equipo tiene más "propiedades":

```
{"equipo": "Nombre_Equipo",
 "puntuacion":
   {"puntuacion 1": XX,
    "puntuacion 2": XX,
    ...
    "puntuacion N": XX
   }
 "jugadores":
   {"jugador 1": XX,
    "jugador 2": XX,
    ...
    "jugador N": XX
   }
}
```

... o alguna combinación de lo anterior!